# CSS not applying if using PHP

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and any data that is within the for loop doesn't have the CSS applied. The file is pointed correctly as all the other css works fine, however I can't find a solution to this anywhere

HTML :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE = html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('/assets/css/home.css')?>">
     <title>Spill.It</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div id="gifLogo">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/homelogo.gif')?>" width="100%" alt="Spill.It Logo">
     </div>
     </header>
<!-- Foreach loop to print all messages from the user. -->
<?php foreach ($messages as $row): ?>
    <div id=messageDisplay>
    <?php if ($row->user_username == null){
        echo '<p>Nothing has been spilt here yet sorry!</p>';
        }?>
    <h1><?php echo $row->user_username;?> : </h1><p><?php echo $row->text;?></p>
    <p id="time"> Posted At :<?php echo $row->posted_at;?></p>

    </div>  
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (I haven't included all the css just the parts within the loop as my css file is very messy) :

```
#messageDisplay {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10em;
    padding-right: 10em;
    border: 1px solid #4099ff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #4099ff;
    margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;   
}
#time {
    font-size: 2px;
}
```

Comment: You should not use IDs for elements that repeat because IDs should be unique to one element in a document, use classes instead. Also I’m not sure where PHP is involved but if you generate your CSS with PHP, make sure you serve the CSS with the correct content-type header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are repeating the CSS IDs. CSS ID can be used once in the whole page as IDs must be unique.

You should use classes instead.

CSS

```
.messageDisplay {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10em;
    padding-right: 10em;
    border: 1px solid #4099ff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #4099ff;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 5px;   
 }
.time {
    font-size: 2px;
 }
```

PHP

```
 <div class="messageDisplay"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing quotes after id , change it to

```
<div id="messageDisplay">
```

Please use classes if you need to design more than one element using same CSS. ID's in a DOM must be unique

Answer (score 0):

Doctype should change like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

---

Loading CodeIgniter assets should be like:

```
href="<?php echo base_url() ;?>assets/css/home.css"
```

So **folder structure** would be:

```
application
assets
    - css
        - home.css
system
index.php
.htaccess
```

---

And in body:

1. wrap id or class with `'` or `"`
2. check out your tag open and close (because there is extra `</div>` in your code)

   ```
   <body>
       <header>
           <div id="gifLogo">
               <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/homelogo.gif" width="100%" alt="Spill.It Logo">
           </div>
        </header>
       <!-- Foreach loop to print all messages from the user. -->
       <?php foreach ($messages as $row): ?>
           <div id= "messageDisplay">
               <?php 
               if ($row->user_username == null)
               {
                   echo '<p>Nothing has been spilt here yet sorry!</p>';
               }
               ?>
               <h1><?php echo $row->user_username;?> : </h1><p><?php echo $row->text;?></p>
               <p id="time"> Posted At :<?php echo $row->posted_at;?></p>
           </div>  
       <?php endforeach ?>
       <!-- </div> -->
   </body>
   ```